# R - change the first two times of a variable in each row into NAs

Tags: r, na

I want the percentage of ones for each year, so the percentage for each column. My problem is now that I have to exclude the first two ones of each row because at that point the individual are to young to be included into my analysis. I tried to change the first two ones into NAs, so I still know that there was a one but it is not included into my analysis/calculations.
The first six rows of my data set (df) looks like the following:

```
    2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
   1    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
   2    0    1    1    1   0     0    0    0
   3    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
   4    1    1    1    0   0     0    0    0
   5    0    1    1    1   0     0    0    0
   6    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
```

The data set should look like the following | expected output:

```
  2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
 1  NA   NA    1    1   1     1    1    1
 2  0    NA   NA    1   0     0    0    0
 3  NA   NA    1    1   1     1    1    1
 4  NA   NA    1    0   0     0    0    0
 5  0    NA   NA    1   0     0    0    0
 6  NA   NA    1    1   1     1    1    1
```

I tried different formulars. Most of them did not worked at all.
The following code at least worked but did not do any change in my data set. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 df2 <- df %>% 
  transmute(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, 
                   (length(x<-which(myRow == 1)) == length(x+1)), NA))
```

I also tried the following but there I got an error:

```
 df3 <- transmute_if (df,(length(x<-which(myRow == 1)) == length(x+1)), return(NA))
```

> Error: `.predicate` must have length 1, not 14.

Comment: You want the % ones in each **row** (across years), not the % ones in each column, am I understanding right? If so, I think you'll need `rowwise` and `c_across`. It would be nice if you'd share your expected output for this sample input--that usually makes things much clearer.

Comment: In general I'd discourage using `<-` inside function calls... `length(x<-which(myRow == 1))` creates a new object `x`, but especially being inside `dplyr` functions it's not at all clear where `x` lives and what its scope is.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas I want the percentage of each column.

Comment: @GregorThomas Putting length(x<-which(myRow == 1)) into a dyplr function was just a try of me to solve my problem in another way because I was not able to write a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R way.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
   1    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
   2    0    1    1    1   0     0    0    0
   3    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
   4    1    1    1    0   0     0    0    0
   5    0    1    1    1   0     0    0    0
   6    1    1    1    1   1     1    1    1
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

f <- function(x){
  i <- which(x == 1)
  if(length(i) ==  1L) {
    is.na(x) <- i
  } else if (length(i >= 2L)) {
    is.na(x) <- i[1:2]
  }
  x
}
t(apply(df1, 1, f))
#>   2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
#> 1   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1
#> 2    0   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    0
#> 3   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1
#> 4   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> 5    0   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    0
#> 6   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

To get proportions of 1's per year, use `colMeans` with `na.rm = TRUE`.

```r
df2 <- t(apply(df1, 1, f))
colMeans(df2, na.rm = TRUE)
#>      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014 
#> 0.0000000       NaN 1.0000000 0.8333333 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And to print as percentages use package `scales`, function `percent` or base R `sprintf`.

```r
scales::percent(colMeans(df2, na.rm = TRUE), accuracy = 0.01)
#>      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014 
#>   "0.00%"        NA "100.00%"  "83.33%"  "50.00%"  "50.00%"  "50.00%"  "50.00%"
sprintf("%2.4g%%", 100*colMeans(df2, na.rm = TRUE))
#> [1] " 0%"    "NaN%"   "100%"   "83.33%" "50%"    "50%"    "50%"    "50%"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Now I have the problem that I am not able to calculate the percentage for each column (without NAs). E.g. for 2010 R should give me 16.67% for 0 and 83.43% for 1. Do you also have a tip/solution for me? I tried `prop.table(df1)`, `prop.table(df1)*100`, `prop.table(table(df1))*100`, `prop.table(table(df1), margin = 2)*100` but the result was wrong.  I also found that others used `df1 %>% group_by (x,y) %>% mutate (percent = round(value / sum(value) * 100, 1)` but I do not have anything (at least I do not know it) to group_by.

Comment: @Bee Do you want percentages or are proportions OK?

Comment: @Bee See the edit, I believe it answers the question.